# Devolver consulta con XPath en JAVA

Tags: java, netbeans, xpath

La idea es crear un método "buscador" que le pase por parámetro la consulta, me devuelve el resultado y lo muestre por pantalla.

Por ejemplo, puedo obtener la información de *//Libro* o */Libros/Libro[./@publicado_en>1900]* (los 3 elementos hijos de Libro), pero no se me da la información, por ejemplo de *//Autor* (Los elementos nieto de Libro)
¿Cómo podría hacer? ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Gracias

**XML**

```
<Libros>
    <Libro publicado_en="1838">
        <Titulo> Oliver Twist </Titulo>
        <Autor> Charles Dickens </Autor>
    </Libro>

    <Libro publicado_en="2005">
        <Titulo> El mar </Titulo>
        <Autor> John Banville </Autor>
    </Libro>

    <Libro publicado_en="1946">
        <Titulo> El principito </Titulo>
        <Autor> Antoine de Saint-Exupéry </Autor>
    </Libro>
</Libros>
```

**Código Java**

```
public String Ejecutar_XPath(String consulta) {
        String salida = "";
        
        try {
            XPathExpression exp = xpath.compile(consulta);
            
            Object result = exp.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            NodeList listaNodos = (NodeList) result;
                    
            for (int i=0; i<listaNodos.getLength(); i++) {
                // salida = salida + listaNodos.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                
                if (listaNodos.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    String[] datos_nodo = procesarLibro(listaNodos.item(i));
                    salida = salida + "\n" + "Publicado en: " + datos_nodo[0];
                    salida = salida + "\n" + "El titulo del libro es: " + datos_nodo[1];
                    salida = salida + "\n" + "El autor del Libro es: " + datos_nodo[2];
                    salida = salida + "\n" + "---------------------";
                }            
            }
            
            return salida;
       } catch (Exception e) {
           return "Error en la ejecución de la consulta";
       }
    }

    private String[] procesarLibro(Node node) {
    String datosDelLibro[] = new String[3];
    Node temporal = null;
    int contador = 1;

    datosDelLibro[0] = node.getAttributes().item(0).getNodeValue();
    NodeList ListaDeNodos = node.getChildNodes();

    for (int i = 0; i < ListaDeNodos.getLength(); i++) {
        temporal = ListaDeNodos.item(i);
        if (temporal.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            datosDelLibro[contador] = temporal.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
            contador++;
        }
    }

    return datosDelLibro;
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error con e.printStackTrace(); es el siguiente:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.w3c.dom.Node.getNodeValue()" because the return value of "org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap.item(int)" is null
    at Xpath.Gestionar_Xpath.procesarLibro(Gestionar_Xpath.java:77)
    at Xpath.Gestionar_Xpath.Ejecutar_XPath(Gestionar_Xpath.java:57)
```

Comment: Trata siempre, durante la construcción del código, de mostrar el contenido de la excepción en vez de simplemente mostrar tu mensaje. Usa `e.printStackTrace()` en el catch y revisa _por qué_ falla tu XPath. Puedes [edit] y traer esa traza :)

Comment: Ya he editado el post con el error que me sale en pantalla con el e.printStackTrace().

Comment: Estás partiendo de la premisa que tienes datos de libro. `datosDelLibro[0] = node.getAttributes().item(0).getNodeValue();` y eso no funciona cuando estás DENTRO de un Libro. TIenes que añádir validaciones o cambiar la estrategia (o restringir los XPath permitidos)

Answer (score 1):

El elemento `Autor` no tiene ningunos attributes, por eso la línea `node.getAttributes().item(0).getNodeValue()` produce el error `"org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap.item(int)" is null`